# css - ::webkit-scrollbar not remove the scroll in chrome

Tags: css

I added

```
.page-content::webkit-scrollbar {
        display: none;
 }
```

But .page-content still display the scroll in some chrome browsers. Seems like it works on mac but not on windows.
Any idea why?

Comment: Try to use that without class selector

Comment: overflow:hidden won't allow you to scroll.. @Dominic

Comment: @Awais I have already tried this..thanks

Comment: Use ::-webkit-scrollbar not ::webkit-scrollbar

Comment: Give background-color: transparent will not display scroll bar.

Comment: thasnk @AkhiAkl!

Answer (score 0):

There you go its not a perfect solution but a hack

> You can set a wrapper around `.page-content` which is `#container1` in
>   below example and then on `.page-content` set some padding `15px` like
>   the width of scroll to hide it.

```css
*{margin:0;}
#container1{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#container2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 99%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

html, body{
    height: 99%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1"><div id="container2">
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    hello<br/>I<br/>am<br/>here<br/>
    good<br/>bye.
</div><div>
```